I have a 1994 chevy s10 4.3 starter issue
I have a 1994 chevy s10 with the 4.3 engine. I have replaced the starter 4 times due to the same issue. After a few months of noemal use when starting I just get a clank noise until it turns over and starts. After while the starter just goes bad and will do nothing when attempting to start then I replace it.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I assume you've purchased a starter from somewhere with a warranty and you're taking the starter back and getting a replacement? If so, I'd suggest you go someplace else and get a new/rebuilt starter. It could very well be that the place you're getting it from gets their remanned starters from someplace which does shoddy work. The starters just may not be good starters to begin with.
